# Can objects be created with default constructor when there is a defined one in a php class?

Tags: php, class, object, constructor

Yes I am confused whether the default constructor(the one automatically made when the class is made and is parameter-less) is still available for construction of an object when I have also defined a parameterized constructor

Comment: There is no such thing but just a magical function that is called when the object is constructed... so no

Comment: and this magical function can be used for creating an object as
    $object=new Object(); //instead of 
    $object=new Object($parameter);//?

Comment: No I think you are thinking of Java.. in PHP constructors don't create objects but are just kind of event listeners for when an object is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you use parametric constructor you need to call it using parameters .PHP doesn't support constructor overloading like C# but their are many workarounds.